# Excel Formula INDEX MATCH with 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the specific population for a country in a certain year. $B4 is a specific country while in an external spreadsheet's column A, hence '[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A contains the name $B4. For row 2, it has the years. Excel is telling me #N/A. I'm not sure what did I do wrong with the formula?

```
=INDEX('[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$3:$BX$291,MATCH($B4,'[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0),MATCH("1999", '[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$2:$2),0)
```

Comment: Your INDEX starts at row 3 and your row match from row 1. That will offset your result, possibly out of range of the indexed range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the penultimate bracket in the wrong place, and you should line your ranges up:

```
=INDEX('[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$3:$BX$291,MATCH($B4,'[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$3:$A$291,0),MATCH("1999", '[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$BX$2,0))
```

or if the year is stored as a number, use:

```
=INDEX('[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$3:$BX$291,MATCH($B4,'[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$3:$A$291,0),MATCH(1999, '[World Population.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$BX$2,0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I stored the year as numbers, so the second one works!